# How to upload the file into web browser through window popup in headless browser in automation (selenium webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bamboo, awtrobot, headless-browser

I need to upload text file into my web page (By Clicking on Browse) through Window popup in selenium.

I have used below robot class to do this.

```
public void uploadFileUsingRobot(String filePath) throws AWTException,Exception{

          StringSelection path = new StringSelection(filePath);
          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(path, null);

              Robot r = new Robot();

              r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
              r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

              r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);    
              r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

              r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);    
              r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

              r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
              r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

       }
```

It's working good in my local. But when i run this through `bamboo` plan, it's not working as bamboo running the code in `headless browser`.

Can anyone suggest me how can i upload the file in `headless browser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your code on bamboo you probably use remote driver. To upload file you can set filepath with sendKeys to file input field and use fileDetector.

**Solution:**

If you have file input field

```
<input id="fileinputfield" type="file">
```

then following code will set filepath

```
remoteWebDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
WebElement input = remoteWebDriver.findElement(By.id("fileinputfield"));
input.sendKeys(filePath);
```

[Here you have an article](https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-uploading-files-in-remote-webdriver) describing solution.

**Possible problems you may reach:**

1. Getting remoteWebDriver. Here is one way you can try

   ```
   RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) ((WebDriverFacade) getDriver()).getProxiedDriver();
   ```
2. Hidden (not displayed) file input field. If html is:

   ```
   <input id="fileinputfield" style="display:none;" type="file">
   ```

   Then you need to display it for time of executing code setting file path:

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
   js.executeScript("document.getElementById('filedata').style.display='inline-block';");

   // RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) ((WebDriverFacade) getDriver()).getProxiedDriver();
   // remoteWebDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
   // WebElement input = remoteWebDriver.findElement(By.id("fileinputfield"));
   // input.sendKeys(filePath);

   js.executeScript("document.getElementById('filedata').style.display='none';");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Java script executor and using robot are not robust.They are working and failing some times.  I tried AutoIt and it's working absolutely fine even in headless/remote browser.